# How to prove that $\int_0^{2\pi} F(\cos x,\sin x)\,dx=\int_c f(z)\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

For an exercise in which I have to solve a real integral using complex techies,in
 the solution chapter of my complex analysis it states that this expression is true, and it's trivial to prove.
I understand that if this expression is true that I can solve integral in question using theorem of residues and the statement My question is how do I prove this expression ?

$$\int_0^{2\pi} F(\cos x,\sin x) \, dx = \int_c f(z) \, dz$$ where $c$ is the circle $|z|=1$ and $$f(z)=\frac{F\left(\frac{z+\frac1z}{2},\frac{z-\frac1z}{2i}\right)}{zi}$$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{align}\require{cancel}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\frac1{zi}F\left(\frac{z+1/z}2,\frac{z-1/z}{2i}\right)\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{\cancel{e^{i\theta}i}}F\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+1/e^{i\theta}}2,\frac{e^{i\theta}-1/e^{i\theta}}{2i}\right)\cancel{ie^{i\theta}}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}F\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2,\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}F(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta.\end{align}